# How many branches of Gaudiya Vaishnava organizations are there?

Tags: gaudiya-vaishnavism, iskcon

We all know about ISKCON, founded by Srila Prabhupada. This is the most popular Gaudiya Vaishnava organisation.

However, I recently came across ISKM (International Society of Krishna Mandir). Their activities are also very similar to ISKCON. This intrigued me.

In total, how many branches are there?  Who were their founders? What are the main differences (if any) between these branches? Can someone list the details on the Gaudiya Vaishnava branches?

Comment: ISKCON got banned in Singapore in 1970s. Shrila Prabhupada wasn't allowed there. Thus, to offically register they changed the name from Isckon to ISKM. It's the same organization, but under different banner.

Comment: @Chamundadas But I have seen their videos and they criticise ISKCON and they claim they are different!

Comment: Nope, ISKM themselves state they want to propound Prabhupada's philosophy in every nook&hook of world. Kindly read this on their official website https://www.iskm.international/about-iskm/

Comment: @Chamundadas Yes, they follow Prabhupada devotedly. They criticise ISKCON'S new Guru parampara. They say their eternal Guru is Prabhupada. So new ones get initiated from him directly. But in ISKCON, new Gurus give initiations.

Comment: Tbh, wht ISKM believes in this matter is against shastras. A human can never make a guru who doesn't hve a body to interact with.However, if one says tht way imagine the Sri Vidya krama has 12 Mahaupaskas.Now, one can't consider Indra or Kamadev as guru & start doing Navarna puja. Thus, initiation from a living guru is must & secondly if the sishya is truly that qualified & tejasvi, the paramguru or even the Paramapara acharya, themselves appears to direct him (I have heard many Shrividyopasakas getting darshan of Durvasa mahamuni& Ashvathama). Thus, in this case ISKCON is absolutely correct.